# How to use li header in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here I used fontawesome icon for play/pause button. In this, you can see output as two play buttons. Since stateicon is used in js and also used as header for two links, play/pause icon not properly working. How to change the #stateicon with corresponding li id.

For example: if I click the second button which is having li header="Stateiconone" then the "stateicon" in js should be updated.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function aud_play_pause(myVar) {
    if (myVar === myTune) {
        var myAudio = document.getElementById("myTune");
    }
    if (myVar === myTunes) {
        var myAudio = document.getElementById("myTunes");
    }
    if (myAudio.paused) {
        $('#stateicon').removeClass('fa fa-play');
        $('#stateicon').addClass('fa fa-pause');
        myAudio.play();
    } else {
        $('#stateicon').removeClass('fa fa-pause');
        $('#stateicon').addClass('fa fa-play');
        myAudio.pause();
    }
}
```

body code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview" onclick="aud_play_pause(myTune)"><i id="stateicon" class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview" onclick="aud_play_pause(myTunes)"><i id="stateiconone" class="fa fa-play"></i></a>

<audio id="myTune">
<source src="http://website.com/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio id="myTunes">
<source src="http://website.com/2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: `id` attribute is supposed to be unique!

Comment: @Uzbekjon - Yes. I know that. I want like "stateicon" in js should be updated with the li header when it is clicked.

Comment: @Turnip - I have problem only with the stateicon in js. It should be updated each time with the respective li header when corresponding link is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't terribly clear but I suspect you are looking for this:

Pass a reference to the clicked element to your function (`this`). Use the reference (`el`) to find the correct `i`. Update the element classes.

```js
function aud_play_pause(myVar, el) {
  if (myVar === myTune) {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("myTune");
  }
  if (myVar === myTunes) {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("myTunes");
  }
  if (myAudio.paused) {
    $(el).find('i').removeClass('fa fa-play');
    $(el).find('i').addClass('fa fa-pause');
    myAudio.play();
  } else {
    $(el).find('i').removeClass('fa fa-pause');
    $(el).find('i').addClass('fa fa-play');
    myAudio.pause();
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview" onclick="aud_play_pause(myTune, this)"><i id="stateicon" class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview" onclick="aud_play_pause(myTunes, this)"><i id="stateicon" class="fa fa-play"></i></a>

<audio id="myTune">
  <source src="http://website.com/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio id="myTunes">
  <source src="http://website.com/2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Thanks Turnip. Perfectly works. Now I able to play both the song at the same time. Is it possible to pause a song if another song get started?

Comment: Sure. Get a reference to both audio elements instead of just one: `var myAudio = document.getElementById("myTune"); var myAudio2 = document.getElementById("myTunes");` pause one and play the other:  `myAudio.play(); myAudio2.pause()`

Comment: I thought this idea but if I use myAudio, myAudio2, myAudio3 then I need to use this statement multiple times. `if (myAudio.paused) {`. Anyway to overcome this?

Comment: You would use `getElementsByTagName` and a loop like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307146/javascript-button-stop-all-audio-on-page

Comment: Thanks Turnip. I think it will help. let my try